# connect two gsp screens to three domains in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

so I am working on a web app when the users click on create on the list screen, it takes them to a page where they have to enter some information and then they click on "next" and it will take them to another gsp page where they have to enter data for two domains but none of the data are stored yet in the tables but when they click on "create" button, everything get stored in the database
I was looking for examples but couldnt find any.
I know how to call the record and edit it since all the domains or the tables share id number so I can use it to retrive data. but my problem is when I transfer from the first gsp screen to another I want to save the instance and then when the users click on create, data goes to the three tables

any idea how to do that? I am still beginner and trying to learn 
thank you

Comment: why can't you save them in database with some kind of extra parameter and have a background job, that deletes all `not_finished` objects that have been idle for more than say 5 minutes?! And session for the user saves object's id to the database.

Comment: I think you may be after jquery-ui tabs that consist of various tabs which gets sent back with 1 submit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468298/displaying-grails-domains-in-jquery-tabs

Answer (score 0):

It sounds kind confusing what you wanna do and I am not sure I completely understood. Because you want to change the whole page, and yet, not to lose those previous answers, right?. Is there a specific reason why you want to do this?

I believe you could sent all the information from the first gsp to a controller and save everything in the "session" (e.g session.name = params.name, session.age = params.age), redirect/render the other gsp and later on, you get the info back from the session plus the info that just came and save everything. This is probably not a very good solution, but this is the only way I figured this out.

:)

Comment: yes exactly I can use a session but if too many users are using the app at the same time, this might take to much memory you know 
so for the first gsp page the user has to enter data for one of the domains and then they click on next but I dont want the data to get stored yet until the user finish filling the second gsp page which is connected to the other two domains and then when the user click create on the second gsp screen. All the data should be stored in the database. 
do you think there is another way to do it instead of sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, I haven't used it until now, but I will some day in the future to modify the dialog-flow in my current application...:

Wouldn't that be a good example for the [**webflow-plugin**](https://grails.org/plugin/webflow)?

Comment: I never used it, but I will try to look it up

Answer (score 0):

This is what command objects are used for. Any time you have a collection of data that you want to collect in a form and then "generate" multiple domain objects from, then this is the way.

The idea is to create a single class that has all the information that you want to collect on the form. You post the filled form data back to the controller save action which then validates that the data is complete using the command object constraints. Once you are happy with everything, you then use the data in the command object to create/update your domain objects.

We consider the use of command objects a Grails best practice. You can  provide custom validation support in the command object that looks for and validates relationships in the data that are difficult to do with the domain objects. We often write factory methods in the command class that produce a new or updated domain object, making it very convenient for unit testing.

See the "Command Objects" section of the "Web Layer" in the manual for details. In Grails 2, command objects are classes with the @Validateable annotation and in Grails 3 they implement the Validateable trait. If you declare your command class as an inner class in the controller, then it is automatically validateable. We've found that we prefer to declare them in src/groovy rather than as inner classes because they are easier for someone unfamiliar with the code to find.

Answer (score 0):

So amongst all of these answers you have your answer but in all honesty I think it is well beyond your own comprehension at this point.

Assuming you have this example as a form

http://code.runnable.com/UevQr3zfd_oaAAGn/jquery-ui-tabs

On tab 1 you have

```
Name
Age
```

On tab 2 you have

```
Address
Postcode
```

Then you have two domain class

```
Class User {
String name
String age
 Address address

}

Class Address {
  String address1
   String postcode
}
```

So a **user** has name age and also binded to address, whilst **address** has address1 and postcode

now your controller action

```
def save(MyBean bean) {
  Address address = new Address(bean.loadAddress()).save()

  User user = new User()
  def userMap = bean.loadUser()
  user.age=userMap.age
  user.name=userMap.name
  //The above object that got saved first
  user.addresss=address
  user.save()

  render "hopefully this should have saved it as expected"
}
```

In `src/main/groovy/yourPackage/MyBean.groovy`

```
package yourPackage

import grails.validation.Validateable

Class MyBean implements Validateable{

  String name
  String age
  Address address
  String address1
  String postcode

  //Now declare your constraints like your domainClass add validator where required to add additional verification/validation to your objects sent back

  //This will return all the objects required as a map to save address domain class
  protected Map loadAddress() {
    Map results=[:]
    results.with {
      address1=address1
      postcode=postcode
    }
    return results
  }
  //this will return the user object
  protected Map loadUser() {
    Map results=[:]
    results.with {
        name=name
        age=age                      
    }
  }
}
```

Other fairly complex validation bean examples:
[PhotosBean](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-bean-validation-examples/blob/master/src/main/groovy/testing/PhotosBean.groovy) [CustomerChatBean](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/beans/CustomerChatTagBean.groovy) [ScheduleBaseBean](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/mailinglist/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/mailinglist/core/ScheduleBaseBean.groovy)

[Other points of reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506941/jquery-ui-tabs-form-submit)

As I say I think as a beginner this may take you a while to get your head around but hoping with what is provided it will become a lot clearer now

**E2A**
*It is really complicated!! can I have two gsp screens instead of jquery tabs*

That doesn't make much sense.

You can have two actions which one just passes params onto 2nd gsp ?

So

```
def TestController  {

  def index() {
    render view: page1
  }

  //where page 1 is the first form and submits to action2
  //action2 picks up parmas from page1
  def action2() {
    render view: page2, model:[params:params]
  }
}
```

in page2.gsp  you have

```
<g:form action="action3">
<g:hiddenField name="originalName" value="${params.originalValue}"/>
<g:hiddenField name="originalName2" value="${params.originalValue2}"/>
<g:hiddenField name="originalName3" value="${params.originalValue3}"/>

Then your actual form content
```

The problem with doing this this way, is does action2 need to verify params received from page1 ? if so it needs to either render original page or page2 depending.

Once submitted to page2 the hiddenFields can be tampered with by end user so what was validated may be invalid now. You will need some form of a way of revalidating all those again.

Using validation methods above you could just call the validate() functions or maybe build some md5 check of initial values vs what is now sent from page2.

Either way if you don't care about validation and just want to see it work then above is the simplest way.

**can I have two gsp screens instead of jquery tabs**

in page1 you can just do `<g:include action="page2">` and include a 2nd gsp within first but in all honesty page 1 could have just contained both actions in 1 page. which is why it don't make sense

Comment: it is really complicated!!
can I have two gsp screens instead of jquery tabs?